# How to get the Custom admin grid collection in custom module template file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid

I want to get the custom admin grid collection in template file. How can I get 
that?

http://i.prntscr.com/c92860d45a904aa4b400ea73b750b8e7.png

I have Used these link to get custom admin grid

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module

I am Using these code in template file to get the collection

**File Path:app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld_index_index.phtml**

```
  $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    //$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\collection');
    /** Apply filters here */

     $collection = $productCollection->create()
                    ->load(1);

    echo count($collection);
```

Can Anyone help me?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Which grid collection you want?

Comment: With my custom module i have created admin grid  show in the screen shot http://prntscr.com/faq36h

Comment: Can you please add code for your current module?

Comment: In need to get the admin grid collection in template file @jaimin Sutariya

Comment: It will require to create blocks file and get your module collection factory in it. If you can add code, it will be helpful to get correct solution.

Comment: $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\collection');
/** Apply filters here */

 $collection = $productCollection->create()
     ->load(1);

echo count($collection); By these way i am unable to get collection

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59158/discussion-between-pranay-k-and-jaimin-sutariya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest not to use `ObjectManager`.

You need to create block, template and layout files for this.
Create a new file **app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Post.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Post extends Template
{
    protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory $mymodulemodelFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    public function getPosts(){
        $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create();
        return $collection;     
    }
}
```

Now create layout file **app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\view\frontend\layout\helloworld_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Post" name="posts" template="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::post.phtml">                
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>               
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create **app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\view\frontend\templates\post.phtml**

```
<?php $collection = $this->getPosts(); ?>
<div class="posts">
    <?php foreach ($collection as $item){ ?>
                 <div class="post">   
                    <?php 
                        // Display your data
                    ?>
                 </div>
     <?php  } ?> 
</div>
```

Now create controller file **app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace  Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }   
}
```

Comment: when code is compiled it is giving warning @Jaimin Sutariya

Comment: What is the warning? can you provide more details?

Comment: [Exception]                                                                  
  Warning: Declaration of Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Post::_construct(Magento  
  \Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Mod  
  el\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory $mymodulemodelFactory, array $data   
  = Array) should be compatible with Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template:  
  :_construct() in /var/www/html/Defaultmagento216/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWo  
  rld/Block/Post.php on line 20

Comment: There was a typo mistake in the code. Please check updated block file code.

Comment: One more question, Can i use addAttributeTofillter in Post.php for getting collection,Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use `$collection->addFieldToFilter('status',1);` to filter your collection.

Comment: Ok,Can i filter by the using attribute

Comment: I am not sure, you can try `addAttributeToFilter`